# Call C# function from C++ with Cocos2dx for WP8 (ex: Facebook sdk)

Tags: c#, c++, facebook, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I'm developing for Windows Phone 8 with the latest release of Cocos-2dx. Is there any way to call C# function from C++? I need to integrate facebook sdk, I searched in internet but could not find any clear example
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the C# source, you should make your C# class ComVisible, after registring this class you may us it from C++.